# Internet Explorer 8 ignores font-weight in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, font-face

So I'm having problems understand why IE is ignoring my CSS here. I have this code:

```
<h2>Har du stadsnät eller kan du få det?</h2>
```

I.e. nothing weird or anything. 
And here is the resulting rendering:

[image: Rendering of HTML]

But here is the CSS code for this HTML:

```
.rubrik, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #969696; 
}
```

Which clearly states that the H2 should have "normal" as font weight, yet the rendered text is clearly bold, here is a correct rendering (from Safari)

[image: Correct rendering]

So, using the included developer tools of Internet Explorer 8, I inspect the CSS interpretation, and that looks like this:

[image: CSS interpretation]

As I understand it, what I am looking at here is IE8's interpretation of my CSS, and suspiciously missing is the "normal" attribute. IE has converted the CSS to the one-line version of "font" but didn't include the "normal" part. Now, the font "Lato" is a font-face font, and the font-face CSS is here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url('/media/fonts/Lato.eot');
    src: local('nofont'), url('/media/fonts/Lato.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url('/media/fonts/Lato-Bold.eot');
    src: local('nofont'), url('/media/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url('/media/fonts/Lato-Bold-Italic.eot');
    src: local('nofont'), url('/media/fonts/Lato-Bold-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url('/media/fonts/Lato-Italic.eot');
    src: local('nofont'), url('/media/fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Even when specifying "normal" in the font-face declaration for font-weight, it doesn't work. So I'm stuck here, trying to figure out what I am doing wrong not to have IE include "font-weight: normal" in the declaration for H2... Any guesses? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try putting the font name in quotes everywhere! Oh and you're defining font-family multiple times with the same name, not sure if IE likes that so much.

Comment: Try using `font-weight: 100;`

Comment: @reinder Quoting the font name doesn't make difference, and IE does pick the correct font, not just the correct weight.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, that does indeed include the "100" in the CSS interpretation, but it doesn't seem to change anything in the actual rendering, possibly because there isn't an according font-weight: 100 in the font-face declaration. I'll test some things with this...

Comment: It's more a hack but you could try to define your font-face names like Lato-normal, Lato-bold etc and use them where you want bold or not...

Comment: don't you need to do something like this for font-face to work in ie: `url('/media/fonts/Lato-Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')` or it may be you need the `.woff` file

Comment: Not reproducible in IE 9 using IE 8 mode. Please post a complete example that demonstrates the issue. Also please specify whether this only happens when using font files hosted by you (and created how?) or also when using files hosted by Google. The Safari screenshort appears to be from a different case, since its text color is different and the weight looks like Book (300) more than normal (400). IE 8 does have problems with font weights lighter than normal, but I cannot reconstruct a problem with normal.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to change the name of the `font-family: Lato;` on each fontface property, as IE is possibly getting confused. Instead try putting `font-family: Lato-bold;`, `font-family: Lato-italic` etc. Also, if the font has a bold face (like Lato does and you have referenced in the fontface properties) then you do not need to add `font-weight: bold;` for a fontface property, as the font is already bold and adding the font-weight will just add faux-bold and make it look bad.

This means that for your `h2`, you only need to put `font-family: Lato;` if you want it to be the normal, non-bold version.

Comment: BUt surely that is in violation of the font-face specification. How would you get bold inline if so? Then I would have to specifically set B and STRONG to font-family: Lato-Bold if the bold state of Lato is not specified?

Comment: Yeah, set b and strong to have a font-family of Lato-bold. If you just set it with font-weight: bold; then you will get double bold (font's uniquely designed bold, and the browser faux-bold) which won't look very good. I also usually set h1, h2, h3 etc to be font-family: Lato-bold; as well when using font-face. This shouldn't be too much of a problem for support/compabilityly, as @font-face is supported by IE6, and most versions of other browsers too: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Answer (score -3):

This may be an inheritance issue. Have you tried putting the !important keyword.

```
font-weight: normal !important;
```

Comment: Indeed I have, this does not include it in the interpretation either, nor change the rendering, unfortunately.

Comment: An explicit declaration cannot be overridden by inheritance; that’s part of the concept of CSS inheritance.