# Incorrect font weight displaying in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I'm testing a page in Internet Exploder 8, and I'm failing to get one of the Google hosted fonts to render the correct weight. Given the following code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400);

h1{
    font-family: 'Lato-Thin', 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

p{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

The paragraph tags renders in 400 weight, but so does the heading. If I change the import line to:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100);
```

The heading no longer renders in Lato, even though the 100 weight is still downloaded.

Is there a way round this?

Here's a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/verism/f2mqbcv1/show/).

Comment: You may need to rename your font file:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891410/internet-explorer-8-ignores-font-weight-in-css

Comment: The Fiddle is in error; due to a syntax error, the paragraph text is not in Lato at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - could you elaborate? It's in Lato here in all tested browsers.

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. It has a trivial but serious syntax error in CSS code for `p`. The part for `h1` works OK (the nonexistent font family name `Lato-Thin` is ignored), so if it does not work in some environment, the problem is apparently in some other code involved.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of it rendering in IE8 - http://imgur.com/uCkd4NC You're right that the 'Lato-Thin' is ignored but I'm not getting a single syntax error. You can clearly see it's the wrong weight. Edit: spotted a missing comma, but even with its inclusion, I get exactly the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a compatibility issue between the way Google serves its custom fonts, and how IE8 would rather them served.

Issue 9 here: https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=9

A workaround is possible if the fonts are stored locally, but that doesn't directly address the problem described in my question.