# Styling Text Elements in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

```css
.title {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pa3ztdwt/

The above fiddle works fine in Google Chrome, but does not work in Internet Explorer 8. It seems that the `font-weight` property is not rendering properly in Internet Explorer 8.

Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047267/ie8-renders-font-weights-randomly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891410/internet-explorer-8-ignores-font-weight-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **text** tag is no defined standard. To add a paragraph use the **p** tag please. I did inspect the tag in IE 8 and as it seems is the  tag directly closed without text within. So you just need to use an allowed tag like **p**

```
<p class='boldText title'>
    sometitle
</p>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bd5Lrkjn/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Standard does not define a `<text>` element. Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) [defines one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text), but you're not using this within the context of an SVG element. Let's look at why this works in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer 8 though, and how (if we wanted to) we could "fix" it.

First, neither Chrome nor Internet Explorer 8 see this as a known element. In Chrome we can create an instance, and check its constructor:

```js
document.createElement( "text" ).constructor; // function HTMLUnknownElement()
```

Although Chrome doesn't recognize this as a known element, it permits styling in spite of that fact. Internet Explorer 8 treats a generic `<text>` element (sans SVG context) in a similar way:

```js
console.log( document.createElement( "text" ) ); // LOG: [object HTMLGenericElement]
```

Internet Explorer handles this as a *generic element*, much in the same way it treats modern elements like `<section>`, `<article>`, and `<canvas>`. These *valid* elements suffered in the same way `<text>` does in that they were difficult to style in older versions of Internet Explorer.

One interesting thing we learned in trying to deliver - anachronistically - modern support to antiquated browsers, is that if you create the element with JavaScript, styling *magically begins working*:

```html
<script>document.createElement( "text" );</script>
<text>This element can now be styled in Internet Explorer 8.</text>
<text>This element can also be styled, because of the effect line 1 has.</text>
```

While all of this is interesting, and fun to study, you *should* avoid doing this. While it's okay to use custom elements, you should avoid creating ambiguity. As mentioned earlier, the `<text>` element belongs to SVG, and should be reserved for those contexts.

If you wish to target an entire block of text or a group of elements, use [*Grouping Elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html). If you would instead like to target a few sentences or words, consider using [*Text-level semantics*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html).

I hope this has been helpful.